# StateListAnimator not working on checkbox

Tags: android, android-layout, animation, checkbox, objectanimator

I am following the article given [here](https://android.jlelse.eu/using-statelistanimators-to-create-instagram-like-animation-db2676c9391)

I am trying to create a "like" button animation and need help since my animator does not seem to be doing anything

I have created the required animator file, created the stateListDrawable file and set it as the background to the CheckBox
The animator file uses a set of objectAnimator  tags which animate the scaleX, scaleY and translationZ properties.

This is my layout file "activity_main.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout    
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkbox"
    android:button="@null"
    android:checked="false"
    android:background="@drawable/like_icon"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:stateListAnimator="@animator/scale2"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is the stateListDrawable "like_icon.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_thumb_up_red_24dp" 
android:state_checked="true" />

<item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_thumb_up_black_24dp" />
</selector>
```

This is my animator named "scale.xml". It is placed correctly in the "res/animator/" folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<objectAnimator
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
    android:propertyName="scaleX"
    android:valueTo="1.525"
    android:valueType="floatType" />

<objectAnimator
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
    android:propertyName="scaleY"
    android:valueTo="1.525"
    android:valueType="floatType" />

<objectAnimator
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
    android:propertyName="translationZ"
    android:valueTo="4dp"
    android:valueType="floatType" />

<objectAnimator
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
    android:propertyName="scaleX"
    android:valueTo="1.0"
    android:startOffset="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
    android:valueType="floatType" />

<objectAnimator
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
    android:propertyName="scaleY"
    android:startOffset="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
    android:valueTo="1.0"
    android:valueType="floatType" />

<objectAnimator
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
    android:propertyName="translationZ"
    android:startOffset="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
    android:valueTo="0dp"
    android:valueType="floatType" />

</set>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the checked states. Try the below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true">
        <set>
            <objectAnimator
                android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
                android:propertyName="scaleX"
                android:valueTo="1.525"
                android:valueType="floatType" />
            
            <objectAnimator
                android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
                android:propertyName="scaleY"
                android:valueTo="1.525"
                android:valueType="floatType" />
            
            <objectAnimator
                android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
                android:propertyName="translationZ"
                android:valueTo="4dp"
                android:valueType="floatType" />
            
            <objectAnimator
                android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
                android:propertyName="scaleX"
                android:startOffset="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
                android:valueTo="1.0"
                android:valueType="floatType" />
            
            <objectAnimator
                android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
                android:propertyName="scaleY"
                android:startOffset="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
                android:valueTo="1.0"
                android:valueType="floatType" />
            
            <objectAnimator
                android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
                android:propertyName="translationZ"
                android:startOffset="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
                android:valueTo="0dp"
                android:valueType="floatType" />
        </set>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While your answer may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. You can edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/28384471)